# Django models and foreign key

Tags: django, database, model, key

this is my first django project and I still seem to have a problem with the concept of foreign keys. I'm using a mysql db and i defined the model (a part/snippet) of the model:

```
class Doctors(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    fachrichtung = models.CharField(max_length=51)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    plz = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    ort = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doctors'

class Leistung(models.Model):
    bezeichnung = models.CharField(max_length=77)
    dauer = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    preis = models.FloatField()
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    artikel = models.ManyToManyField(Artikel)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'leistung'

class Behandlung(models.Model):
    datum = models.DateField()
    re_nr = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    doctor = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    istpreis = models.FloatField()
    leistungs_text = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    leistung = models.ForeignKey('Leistung', models.DO_NOTHING)
    verrechnet_am = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'behandlung'

class Rechnung(models.Model):
    id =models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctors', models.DO_NOTHING)
    erstellt_am = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='rechnung'
```

when i start the server and want to produce an entry to Rechnungen with the following lines:

```
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')          
#doctorid is a parameter passed to the view method
doc = Doctors.objects.get(id=doctorid)     
rechnung = Rechnung(doctor=doc.id,erstellt_am=date)
rechnung.save()
```

i get the following error:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'doctor_id' in 'field list'")
```

when i run:

```
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')                  
#doctorid is a parameter passed to the view method
doc = Doctors.objects.get(id=doctorid)         
rechnung = Rechnung(doctor=doc, erstellt_am=date)
rechnung.save()
```

i get the same error. So i then tried to rename the doctor column to doctor_id in Rechnungen. But then i get an error

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <Doctors: AP>.
```

so i deleted the **str** method from the model but ended up with the same error.. and after that i modified my code to:

```
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')                          
#doctorid is a parameter passed to the view method
doc = Doctors.objects.get(id=doctorid)             
rechnung = Rechnung(doctor=doc.id, erstellt_am=date)
rechnung.save()
```

which brings me back to my first error. And i have the feeling of running in circles. I also tried to pass the doctorid to `Rechnung(doctor=doctorid, erstellt_am=date)` but it requires a doctor instance. So before getting to delete the foreign key, does anyone have a suggestion to how i can solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run all your migrations?

Comment: Can you try with `Rechnung(doctor_id=doctorid, erstellt_am=date)`?

Comment: @Vincent yes  i ran all the migrations!

Comment: @ruddra i will try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual guess the integer field is not auto incremented in doctor model to solve this problem make delete all the data in the database if possible and after that you have to do edit the following id field in doctors model

```
class Doctors(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
Or

class Doctors(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

after this apply

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment:  well it is not just a guess, it is the best guess! Thank you! Apparently, working with ids which are not generated by the db isn't ok. Had to reset all my migrations, re-design the model, migrate it and adjust forms, templates, views according to the new model .. Thanks again!

Comment: Its my pleasure 